# Identifying start and end of period covered - oracle 10g sql

Tags: sql, oracle, list, date, oracle10g

I have data that looks like this:

```
        ID      FROM        TO          START_CODE      END_CODE    TYPE
        A       01/01/2012  02/02/2012  P               E           1
        A       12/03/2011  01/01/2012  P               X           1
        A       01/01/2011  12/03/2011  S               X           2

        A       01/01/2010  02/02/2010  P               E           2
        A       12/03/2010  01/01/2010  P               X           4
        A       01/01/2009  12/03/2009  S               X           1
```

Basically, this is information for one client.  The end_code 'e' denotes the end of a period of care, the start_code 's' denotes a start of a period of care.  A start code of 'p' denotes the dates are a continuation, as does an end code of 'x'.  What I would like to be able to return is data that looks like the following:

```
        ID      START       END             Types
        A       01/01/2011  02/02/2012      2,1,1
        A       01/01/2009  02/02/2010      1,4,2
```

The query for the first table looks similar to this (example only), however, I would be interested in returning for a number of clients, and not just 'A'.

```
        SELECT
        A.ID,
        A.FROM,
        A.TO,
        A.START_CODE,
        A.END_CODE,
                       A.Type

        WHERE
        A.ID = 'A'
```

I've used xmlagg in the past to achieve similar things (i.e. to list information in one cell), but it's actually identifying seperate start and end dates for each client, and then returning the sequence of types that I'm struggling with.  For reference, my oracle version is 10g, 10.2.0.5.0.

Thanks for your time, any pointers or assistance is appreciated.

Edited to include suggestion by A.B.Cade below:

```
        SELECT
        t3.MOV_PER_GRO_ID,
        t3.f,
        t3.MOV_END_DATE,
        t3.types,
        LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(t3.types,'[^,]')) as "Count"
        FROM(

        SELECT 
        sys_connect_by_path(t2.MOV_2000_PLACEMENT_TYPE,',') types,
        connect_by_root(t2.MOV_START_DATE) f, 
        t2.MOV_START_DATE,        
        t2.MOV_END_DATE,        
        connect_by_isleaf is_leaf, 
        t2.MOV_PER_GRO_ID 
        FROM (SELECT t.*,
        lag(t.MOV_START_DATE) over (ORDER BY t.MOV_PER_GRO_ID, t.MOV_START_DATE) nfrom
        FROM O_MOVEMENTS t
        WHERE t.MOV_PER_GRO_ID IN ('A','B'))t2 
        START 
        WITH 
        t2.MOV_2000_START_REASON = 'S'
        CONNECT BY   
        PRIOR t2.MOV_START_DATE = t2.nfrom
        AND PRIOR t2.MOV_PER_GRO_ID =  t2.MOV_PER_GRO_ID 
        AND t2.MOV_2000_START_REASON IN ('P'))t3
        where t3.is_leaf=1
```

Updated based on ABCade's solution.  After a few tweaks (again thanks to ABCade) it appears to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT  t3."ID", t3.f "start", t3."TO" "end", t3.types
FROM (
SELECT sys_connect_by_path(t2."TYPE",',') types,
       connect_by_root(t2."FROM") f,
       t2."FROM",
       t2."TO",
       connect_by_isleaf is_leaf ,
t2."ID"
FROM (
  SELECT t.*, lag(t."FROM") over (ORDER BY t."FROM") nfrom
    FROM table1 t
   WHERE t."ID" = 'A'
  ) t2
START WITH t2."START_CODE" = 'S'
CONNECT BY   PRIOR t2."FROM" = t2.nfrom  AND t2."START_CODE" = 'P') t3
WHERE is_leaf=1
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c2ed/4) is a fiddle
[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e686/1) is another fiddle (after seeing your comment and update)

Comment: Thanks for this, I've never seen a query that uses the sys_connect_by_path before, but I'll try this out as soon as I'm able.  Many thanks.

Comment: @bawpie, it's hard to say without having your tables definition and some real data sample, but my guess is that it's related to some assumptions I made: 1) There can be gups in the periods (this is why I used `lag` and couldn't trust `prior from = to`, 2) That there are no overlaps in periods. I didn't take into consideration the use of "ID" field. If assumption (2) is correct but only for every "ID" then adding `WHERE t."ID"='A'` in the most inner select should do.

Comment: @ABCade - Thanks, I have it working now for one ID (updated code in the query).  If I try to run it on more than one id sometimes I get an error about ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data, does there need to be something in the connect by that references the ID?  I'm afraid I'm not familiar with using connect by.

Comment: @ABCade - Added the id into the orderby for the lagg, and it's running the query successfully now(see updated code above).  I need to check the results, so fingers crossed!

Comment: @ABCade - That change is giving strange results, the the period being split into seperate periods in some cases (but not in others?).

Comment: @bawpie, no, that defently won't work... (addidng id='A' works because it takes only on specific id). You need to make the `connect by` work only on the same IDs. I can't check it now, but try: `CONNECT BY   PRIOR t2."FROM" = t2.nfrom AND PRIOR t2."ID"=t2."ID" AND t2."START_CODE" = 'P'`

Comment: @ABCade - I can see now that that wouldn't work.  I've tried to the connect by as suggested, but it seems to be splitting up the episodes into smaller chunks - no record has more than 3 types now, which isn't right (though if I understand the prior correctly I think I understand why it's doing it).  Thanks for your patience and suggestions.

Comment: @bawpie, another thing - we need to get the lag(from) ordered for every "ID". So try- `lag(t."FROM") over (ORDER BY t."ID", t."FROM")`

Comment: @ABCade - I think that's done the trick!  I'll post the updated solution and double check, but early signs look promising.  Thanks!