# Identifying start and end of assignment oracle sql 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle10g, connect-by

This is very similar to a question I have already asked (and had answered) here: [Identifying start and end of period covered - oracle 10g sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912279/identifying-start-and-end-of-period-covered-oracle-10g-sql)

However, I've not been able to work out how to achieve what I need in this case.  I have data that looks like this:

```
ID  Start            End    End Code        Worker ID
A   02/08/2003  23/01/2007  A               1
A   24/01/2007  17/11/2008  J               2
A   03/03/2009  20/10/2009  A               3
A   21/10/2009  08/03/2010  A               4
A   09/03/2010  29/07/2010  A               5
A   30/07/2010                              6
```

The end code 'A' means that a case has been reassigned, 'J' means that it has been closed. I would like data that looks like the following:

```
     ID Start             End   Worker IDs  End Worker
     A  02/08/2003  17/11/2008  1,2         2
     A  03/03/2009              3,4,5,6     6
```

As I've already said, this is very similar to a previous question I've asked, but in that case there was a start code I could utilise.  I think I need to identify the beginning of the assignment- it's either the first date that follows an assignment with a 'J' code, or just the earliest date but I'm struggling a bit.  Any advice appreciated!  For reference, my oracle version is 10g, 10.2.0.5.0.

Edit: Accepted answer provided by @Dazzal as it answered my original query but I've posted a new question based on @Gordon Linoff's answer, as I think this will more fit my needs.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383560/grouping-data-oracle-sql-based-on-sum

Comment: does the ordering of "worker IDs" matter?

Comment: Sorry, just saw this.  It'd be nice to have it in order but not essential.  I see you've added two solutions, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if worker ids ordering is unimportant, use a built in aggregate function.

```
SQL> select id, min(start_date), max(case when last_worker is not null then end_date end) end_date,
  2         wm_concat(worker_id) worker_ids, max(last_worker) last_worker
  3    from (select id, start_date, end_date, end_code, worker_id, case when end_code ='J' or end_date is null then worker_id end last_worker,
  4                 nvl(max(r) over (partition by id order by end_date nulls last), 1) r
  5    from (select t.*,
  6                  case
  7                    when lag(end_code, 1) over (partition by id order by end_date nulls last) = 'J' then
  8                     row_number() over(partition by id order by end_date nulls last)
  9                  end r
 10             from test t)
 11  )
 12  group by id, r;

I MIN(START END_DATE  WORKER_IDS           LAST_WORKER
- --------- --------- -------------------- -----------
A 02-AUG-03 17-NOV-08 1,2                            2
A 03-MAR-09           3,6,5,4                        6
```

is it is, you'll have to make your own aggregate function. eg here's one i use on 10g:

```
SQL> select id, min(start_date), max(case when last_worker is not null then end_date end) end_date,
  2         stragg_num(stragg_num_typ(worker_id, ',', worker_id)) worker_ids, max(last_worker) last_worker
  3    from (select id, start_date, end_date, end_code, worker_id, case when end_code ='J' or end_date is null then worker_id end last_worker,
  4                 nvl(max(r) over (partition by id order by end_date nulls last), 1) r
  5    from (select t.*,
  6                  case
  7                    when lag(end_code, 1) over (partition by id order by end_date nulls last) = 'J' then
  8                     row_number() over(partition by id order by end_date nulls last)
  9                  end r
 10             from test t)
 11  )
 12  group by id, r;

I MIN(START END_DATE  WORKER_IDS           LAST_WORKER
- --------- --------- -------------------- -----------
A 02-AUG-03 17-NOV-08 1,2                            2
A 03-MAR-09           3,4,5,6                        6

SQL>
```

the definition of which is:

```
drop function stragg;
drop function stragg_num;
drop type string_agg_type;
drop type stragg_vc_tab;
drop type stragg_vc_typ;
drop type stragg_num_tab;
drop type stragg_num_typ;
create or replace type stragg_vc_typ as object
(
  value   varchar2(4000),
  delim   varchar2(10),
  rown    varchar2(4000)
);
/
create or replace type stragg_vc_tab
as table of stragg_vc_typ;
/
show errors type stragg_vc_tab
create or replace type stragg_num_typ as object
(
  value   varchar2(4000),
  delim   varchar2(10),
  rown    integer
);
/
show errors type stragg_num_typ
create or replace type stragg_num_tab
as table of stragg_num_typ;
/
show errors type stragg_num_tab


create or replace type string_agg_type as object
(
   total clob,
   delim   varchar2(10),
   data    stragg_num_tab,
   data2    stragg_vc_tab,

   static function
        ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT string_agg_type )
        return number,

   member function
        ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT string_agg_type ,
                             value IN stragg_num_typ )
        return number,

   member function
        ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT string_agg_type ,
                             value IN stragg_vc_typ )
        return number,

   member function
        ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN string_agg_type,
                               returnValue OUT  varchar2,
                               flags IN number)
        return number,

   member function
        ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                           ctx2 IN string_agg_type)
        return number
);
/
show errors type string_agg_type
create or replace type body string_agg_type
is


static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT string_agg_type)
return number
is
begin
    sctx := string_agg_type( null, null, null, null );
    return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                                     value IN stragg_num_typ )
return number
is
begin
    if (delim is null)
    then
      delim := value.delim;
    end if;
    if (data is null)
    then
      data := stragg_num_tab();
    end if;
    data.extend;
    data(data.last) := value;
    return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                                     value IN stragg_vc_typ )
return number
is
begin
    if (delim is null)
    then
      delim := value.delim;
    end if;
    if (data2 is null)
    then
      data2 := stragg_vc_tab();
    end if;
    data2.extend;
    data2(data2.last) := value;
    return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN string_agg_type,
                                       returnValue OUT varchar2,
                                       flags IN number)
return number
is
  v_delim  varchar2(10);
begin
    if data is not null 
    then
      for r_item in (select d.value
                       from table(data) d
                      order by d.rown)
      loop
        returnValue := returnValue || v_delim || r_item.value;
        v_delim := self.delim;
      end loop;
    else
      for r_item in (select d.value
                       from table(data2) d
                      order by d.rown)
      loop
        returnValue := returnValue || v_delim || r_item.value;
        v_delim := self.delim;
      end loop;
    end if;
    return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT string_agg_type,
                                   ctx2 IN string_agg_type)
return number
is
begin
    self.total := self.total || ctx2.total;
    return ODCIConst.Success;
end;


end;
/
show errors type body string_agg_type
CREATE or replace FUNCTION stragg_num(input stragg_num_typ )
RETURN varchar2
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING string_agg_type;
/

CREATE or replace FUNCTION stragg(input stragg_vc_typ )
RETURN varchar2
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING string_agg_type;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Our system has just gone down for maintenance, but I'll test this first thing next week.

Comment: Hi, tried this this morning.  It seems to be working perfectly, thanks.  What it's shown me is that the recording of using the 'J' as an end date is not as robust as it should be, so I'm going to check @GordonLinoff's solution as that just looks at dates rather than the code.  Thanks!

Comment: @bawpie if you want to order by date instead of a number/varchar using the above its simple. you could do this: `stragg(stragg_vc_typ(worker_id, ',', to_char(your_date_field, 'yyyymmddhh24miss'))` or of couse add a date type `create or replace type stragg_date_typ as object
(
  value   varchar2(4000),
  delim   varchar2(10),
  rown    date);` and then add this new object to a function + overload it in the object. @GordonLinoff suggested listagg but you said that you're on 10g so that wouldn't work, as its an 11g thing.

Comment: where would I put the stragg(stragg_vc_typ(worker_id, ',', to_char(your_date_field, 'yyyymmddhh24miss')) in the query?  Would it be to replace wm_concat?  I've tried doing that but I get a Exception: DBD, ORA-00904: "STRAGG": invalid identifier error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with set operations.  The following identifies periods where there is no gap -- that is, does not use end codes.  It determines if the record starts a period using the `lag` function.  It then does a cumulative sum to identify the members within a group, and then an aggregation to bring them together.

```
select groupnum, MIN(start) as start,
       (case when GroupSeqNum = NumInGroup then max(end) end) as end,
       listagg(WorkerId delimiter ',' order by start) as WorkerIds,
       (case when GroupSeqNum = NumInGroup then max(WorkerId) end) as EndWorker
from (select t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id, groupnum order by start) as GroupSeqNum,
             COUNT(*) over (partition by id, groupnum) as NumInGroup     
      from (select t.*,
                   SUM(IsStart) over (partition by id order by start) as GroupNum
            from (select t.*,
                         (case when lag(end) over (partition by id order by start) = start - 1 then 0 else 1 end) as IsStart
                  from t
                 ) t
           ) t
    ) t
```

If you are identifying groups by ending with a "J" code, simply change the definition of IsStart to:

```
                     (case when lag(EndCode) over (partition by id order by start) = 'J' then 0 else 1 end) as IsStart
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm just looking at this now and think that this would suit me best as a solution, however, there's no group by at the end so it's throwing me an error about that (Exception: DBD, ORA-00937: not a single-group group function State: N/A).  I either need to throw in some over partion by's into the outer query, or have a group by at the bottom but I can't quite figure it out.  Looking at what the inner query returns, I can see the istart is right.

Comment: @pawpie would this work for you? as you said you had 10g which does not have listagg (11g) ?

Comment: @DazzaL - the listagg won't work, you're right.  However, it's not a huge priority to have the list of workers, more that I don't need to rely on the 'J' code being used to identify the end of an allocation.